# Inserting record when there is no element present

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a insert data only when the corresponding enter is not present under db .

This is working only when there is atleast one record present otherwise its not working

This is my table

The insert query only when there is atleast one entry present or else its not working

this is my fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/688409

Comment: You don't have the same named fields in your query / table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `union` to do that:

```
INSERT INTO test_details (test_name,order_of_dispaly, test_status, system_generated)
```

Comment: thank you but with this duplicate is also being inserted

Comment: There is no duplicated record in sql fiddle demo above. Or could you provide some sample data and desired result please? @UnKnown

Comment: in the above fiddle the name with tester already exists so it must not insert new record .

Comment: @UnKnown Updated my answer, please try again.